# Aggregating or summing field by two or more criteria using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, aggregation, summarizing

I am using QGIS 2.18.

I'm trying to sum fields based on two criteria with filed calculator.

I have the "ID" field and the "ZONE" field (ID is secondary key, repited for other table). ZONE field has a value 01;02;03.I want to summarize the field "VALUE"  based on the ID field, and ZONE field.

aggregate( 'ID', 'sum' , "VALUE" , "ZONE" = 01)

aggregate( 'ID', 'sum' , "VALUE" , "ZONE" = 02) ect.

[image]

Comment: What is your question? A single question mark somewhere in your question body would make that obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sum()` instead.

```
sum("Value", group_by:= concat("ID", "ZONE"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nagib `aggregate()` is an excellent function when you work across multiple layers. It only lacks `group_by` option, so I recommended `sum()`.